# Hide Wordpress shopping cart coupon when text not found

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

using wordpress plugin WP Simple Shopping Cart on my site , and it has limitations in that if you set up a coupon code for users to fill out during checkout, it always shows regardless if the items they are buying is related to the coupon offered. So i wanted to only display the coupon when a specific string of text is displayed. Since the coupon only applies to items with the word "package" in them , I want to hide the coupon area in all instances except when "package" is found in the HTML

so need to do this , and i don't have a clue how to

```
<div class="shopping_cart">
<table>    
<tbody>
<!-----  ALWAYS SHOW COUPON CONTAINER FOR ITEMS CONTAINING TEXT "package"  ------>   

<tr><td><a href="http://www.nitrografixx.com/easy-slide-v1/">PRODUCT WITH TEXT CONTAINING WORD PACKAGE</a></td>

<tr>
<!-----  ALWAYS HIDE COUPON CONTAINER FOR ITEMS NOT CONTAINING TEXT "package"  ------>
<td><a href="http://www.nitrografixx.com/nike-light/">PRODUCT WITH NOT TEXT CONTAINING WORD PACKAGE</a></td>

</tr>
<!-----  COUPON CONTAINER  ------>
<div class="wpspsc_coupon_section"></div>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with jQuery:

```
function couponDisplay() {
    var couponValid = jQuery('.shopping a:contains(package)').length;
    jQuery('.wpspsc_coupon_section').toggle(couponValid);

}
```

It's not clear if you need this only on a checkout page or need it in dynamically populated cart.
You will have to insert code accordingly.

The argument for `:contains()` selector is also case sensitive. If a solution is needed for different cases would need to modify above to use `filter()` method

Comment: would you have any idea where to place this ? Its only being used on the shopping cart page

Comment: depends on how cart works, if it is only a single page, place in code loaded on that page, if it is for cart on every page would need to tie into into cart loading